# How can I find the Kernel Map offset on iOS 9.3.5 iPod Touch 5?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I am trying to build a tool around the v0rtex exploit released on GitHub a while back and I need to find the offset for Kernel Map and for Realhost.

I have decrypted the kernel file from the ipsw and loaded it in IDA but the offset I obtain never seems to be correct. The phone errors out.

The offset I managed to locate: `0x2b2b`

Comment: I think the "jailbreak" tag would have been more appropriate here. Also you may wanna check how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't show what you've tried, and your effort. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a valid offset.

I assume you mean the `KERNEL_MAP` and `REALHOST` offsets.

If you already have the decrypted `kernelcache` file on your desktop, and you are doing this on macOS (which I assume you do since you're building an iOS app, here's one of the methods to find the offsets:

1. Place your `kernelcache` file on Desktop and make sure it's called "kernelcache".
2. Open Terminal and paste the following commands:

For `KERNEL_MAP`:

```
nm kernelcache | grep ' _kernel_map$' | awk '{ print "0x" $1 }'
```

For `REALHOST`:

This is a bit trickier. `REALHOST` is actually `host_priv_self_addr`
You need to make sure you have Radare2 installed.

If you don't have radare2, install it with

```
brew install radare2
```

After that, run:

```
host_priv_self_addr=$(nm kernelcache | grep host_priv_self | awk '{ print "0x" $1 }')
    r2 -q -e scr.color=false -c "pd 2 @ $host_priv_self_addr" kernelcache 2> /dev/null | sed -n 's/0x//gp' | awk '{ print $NF }' | tr '[a-f]\n' '[A-F] ' | awk '{ print "obase=16;ibase=16;" $1 "+" $2 }' | bc | tr '[A-F]' '[a-f]' | awk '{ print "0x" $1 }'
```

Put this in a .sh file, give it proper permissions with `chmod +x`.

IMPORTANT: Kernel file MUST be decrypted with proper KEY + IV from https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Genoa_13G36_(iPod5,1)

Took some time and ran these against an IPSW of 9.3.5 for iPod Touch 5th Generation that I had around. `KERNEL_MAP` offset is `0x80412010`.

You'll have to find the other one yourself.

Comment: Does this work on 33-bit kernel?

Comment: I assume you mean 32-Bit? Yes. As long as the kernel file is decrypted. Do keep in mind everything until iOS 10 is encrypted by default. You may need a key + iv from TheiPHoneWiki if your kernel is encrypted otherwise none of the commands I gave you will work.

Comment: I decrypted with lzssdec. I don’t recall using any keys.

Comment: No. lzssdec is for decompressing the kernel. That's a whole different animal. You need a different tool, like Decrypt0r (https://github.com/matteyeux/Decrypt0r) to decrypt the file using the KEY + IV from here: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Genoa_13G36_(iPod5,1)